# SQL Order by particular letters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, table, order-by

[image: BarDetailId Table]

```
@BarId AS INTEGER

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
   SELECT [BarDetailId]
  ,[BarId]
  ,[Member]
  ,[MemberNo]
  ,[BarMark]
  ,[TypeSize]
  ,[BarLength]
  ,[BarNo]
  ,[BarTotal]
  ,[ShapeCode]
  ,[ShapeImage]
  ,(SELECT CASE WHEN DimA <> 0 THEN 'A=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimA AS 
   Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimB <> 0 THEN 
        ', B=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimB AS Decimal(18, 0)))
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimC <> 0 THEN 
        ', C=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimC AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimD <> 0 THEN 
        ', D=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimD AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimE <> 0 THEN 
        ', E=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimE AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimF <> 0 THEN 
        ', F=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimF AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimG <> 0 THEN 
        ', G=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimG AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN DimN <> 0 THEN 
        ', N=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(DimN AS Decimal(18, 0))) 
    ELSE '' END) AS Dimension
  ,[DimA]
  ,[DimB]
  ,[DimC]
  ,[DimD]
  ,[DimE]
  ,[DimF]
  ,[DimG]
  ,[DimN]
  ,[Remark]
  ,[Active]
  ,[CreatedDtTm]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[CreatedIp]
  ,[UpdatedDtTm]
  ,[UpdatedBy]
  ,[UpdatedIp]
   FROM BAR_SCHEDULE_DETAIL WHERE Active = 1 AND BarId = @BarId 

   END
   END
```

I want to order by Typesize with the first letter T then number, after that start with letter R, I have tried numerous example but it does not seem to function properly. For Example i want the order to be like T10, T12, T16, R10, R12, R16

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/dynamic-sorting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to sort (descending) by the first character of TypeSize first and the sort the next 4 characters of that same column in ascending order.

In the following example solution, I've used the `SUBSTRING` function to 'pick-out' the first character and sort it in descending order (so the 'T',s will come before the 'R's), and then I used the `SUBSTRING` function to 'pick-out' the next 3 characters and sort that in ascending order.

The 3rd parameter of the `SUBSTRING` function references the length.  The TypeSize column is variable length, so you can't simply hardcode the number '4' for the length parameter.  **R06.8** has 4 characters after the first character, but **R10** only has 3 characters.  If you hard-coded the number 4 for the length of the `SUBSTRING` function, it might error out when processing that data.  That's why I 'calculate' the length of the rest of the data by using the `LEN` function and then subtract 1 because that gets me past the first character. The length of the data for **R06.8** is a total of 5 characters, so subtracting 1 gives me the proper length of data for the `SUBSTRING` function.  The length of the data for **R10** is only 3 characters, so subtracting 1 give me the proper length of the data for that as well.

```
declare @Test table (col1 nvarchar(5))
insert into @test values('T10'), ('T12'), ('T16'), ('R06.8'), ('R08.3'), ('R10')

select * from @Test order by substring(Col1,1,1) desc, substring(col1,2,len(col1)-1)
```

As I indicated in my comments, there are probably numerous (and possibly more efficient) ways of solving this problem.  Hopefully you will understand my solution.  Let me know if I have misunderstood your requirements.